# How to order by column A and then by column B?

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by

How to write SQL so that the result can be ordered first by column A then by column B. Something like below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE predictor ORDER by col_A and ORDER by col_B
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

```
ORDER BY col_A, col_B
```

The SQLite website has [syntax diagrams](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#select-stmt) explaining the SQL grammar supported by SQLite.

Comment: What if I need col_A as asc then col_B as desc

Comment: You can put asc, desc after each column, eg: ORDER BY col_A asc, col_B desc

Comment: This is also the correct syntax (including the above comment's reference to using ASC and DESC) for T-SQL for SQL Server.

Answer (score 25):

Just feed a comma separated list of columns to ORDER BY:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE table.foo=bar ORDER BY colA, colB
```

> The ORDER BY clause causes the output
>   rows to be sorted. The argument to
>   ORDER BY is a list of expressions that
>   are used as the key for the sort. The
>   expressions do not have to be part of
>   the result for a simple SELECT, but in
>   a compound SELECT each sort expression
>   must exactly match one of the result
>   columns. Each sort expression may be
>   optionally followed by a COLLATE
>   keyword and the name of a collating
>   function used for ordering text and/or
>   keywords ASC or DESC to specify the
>   sort order.

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE predictor ORDER by col_A, col_B
```